# Python split by "%NumberNumber"

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have the following strings for example

```
mystr = "Thisisaexample123%20321Lorem%29Ipsum%28Bad123Example%20Hopefully"
```

What i am trying to achieve is:

```
array = mystr.split("%NumberNumber")
for unit in array:
    print(unit)
```

Console:

```
Thisisaexample123
321Lorem
Ipsum
Bad123Example
Hopefully
```

Hm... maybe using Regex?

Comment: wouldn't it be `Lorem` in the 2nd line. In that case use `re.split("%\d+",str)` (and don't call your variable `str`)

Comment: No it should be 321Lorem, I want it to be splitted by every percentage symbol % that is followed by 2 numbers. 
Alternatively I want all %NumberNumber to be replaced with ";" so i can split at ";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `re.split` using `%\d\d` as the splitting regex. (percent & 2 digits)

```
import re

print("\n".join(re.split("%\d\d","Thisisaexample123%20321Lorem%29Ipsum%28Bad123Example%20Hopefully")))
```

result:

```
Thisisaexample123
321Lorem
Ipsum
Bad123Example
Hopefully
```

(aside: don't use `str` as a variable name as it's the built-in string object name)